# How to redirect the old page url to new page url in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, url, google-analytics

I just upgraded my website and now old URL like www.mywebsite.com/mypage.html becomes new SEO based url www.mywebsite.com/mypage .... now how i will tell the "Google Analytics" to update my old url to new?? so it will not effect on my page ranking.

Thanks :D

Comment: Google Analytics and page ranking are not linked I think.

Comment: they aren't google analytics simply logs views on the website

Answer (score 1):

Setup a 301 redirect on all of the *.html pages to their new respective pages and Google will work it out on its own, also if you have Webmaster tools setup submit a new sitemap with the new pages.